# Missing character U+003B LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex

I use LuaLaTeX, with `\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}`. After compiling, I get a single error:
`[87] Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!`, although on page 87 I can see the only semicolon correctly displayed. I cannot see any other semicolon that could cause the problem.
For that matter, I have many semicolons in the text, why this particular page became a problem?
True, I use a `pgf` plot on that page, too -- could this mess things up?

Comment: You don't give many clues but my guess would be that you have a mis-placed `;` in `tikz` (which uses nullfont to mask several user errors that would cause typeset text)

Comment: You were right. I had a ``legend{...}`` entry in a ``pgfplot`` with a semicolon at the end. I removed it, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tikz uses `\nullfont` (that has no characters) to mask user errors with misplaced syntax that would "fall through" as typeset text. (Arguably it would be better if it gave a real error rather than try to be forgiving, but it does what it does)  so if you put a `;` in your tikz lines at a point tikz is not expecting a `;` then you are likely to see the warning that you show in the log.